# R Conditional Regression with Multiple Conditions

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to run a regression in R based on two conditions.  My data has binary variables for both year and another classification.  I can get the regression to run properly while only using 1 condition:

```
# now time for the millions of OLS
# format: OLSABCD where ABCD are binary for the values of MSA/UA and years
# A = 1 if MSA, 0 if UA
# B = 1 if 2010
# C = 1 if 2000
# D = 1 if 1990

OLS1000<-summary(lm(lnrank ~ lnpop, data = subset(df, msa==1)))
OLS1000
```

However I cannot figure out how to get both the MSA/UA classification to work with the year variables as well.  I have tried:

```
OLS1100<-summary(lm(lnrank ~ lnpop, data = subset(df, msa==1, df$2010==1)))
OLS1100
```

But it returns the error:

> Error: unexpected numeric constant in "OLS1100<-summary(lm(lnrank ~ lnpop,
> data = subset(df, msa==1, df$2010"

How can I get the program to run utilizing both conditions?

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
df$2010
```

If your data really has a column named `2010`, then you need backticks around it:

```
df$`2010`
```

And in your subset, don't specify df twice:

```
subset(df, msa == 1, `2010` == 1)
```

In general it's better if column names don't start with digits. It's also best not to name data frames `df`, since that's a function name.

Comment: Thank you!  Also, I realized I made a new matrix when I changed some variables into log form and essentially was calling from two different matrices.

Answer (score 0):

@neilfws pointed out the "numeric as column names issue", but there is actually another issue in your code.

The third argument of `subset()` is actually reserved for the `select =`, which lets you choose which columns to include (or exclude). So the correct syntax should be:

```
subset(df, msa == 1 & `2010` == 1)
```

instead of

```
subset(df, msa == 1, `2010` == 1)
```

This second code would not give you an error, but it also would not give you the right condition.