# R syntax: manually write logistic model with an if variable

Tags: r, syntax, regression, logistic-regression, glm

I am trying to manually write a model that corresponds to [ROI severity score](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6655747/) for burn prognostic value. This is a multivariate logistic regression model described [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6655747/). Basically models are logistic regression models:
[image]

whose coefficients for each variable included in the model are listed in the table below:
[image: ROI model]

I am trying to manually write this specific model in R:

```
death ~ PTB + FTB + I(PTB*FTB) + I(FTB^2) + I(PTB*I(FTB^2)) + factor(age_under_2) + age + I(age^2) + I(age^3) + factor(GENIT) + factor(SEX) + admission_time
```

But I cannot figure out how to syntactically include the `age less/more than 2 years` variable correctly. In fact, in the model above I used a factor variable `age2` which is `1` if age is <2 and `0` otherwise.

But this is incorrect as `age` itself is then considered in all the other ways (`age + I(age^2) + I(age^3)`) even if age is <2.

How can I correctly write such model so age is interpreted correctly as factor if is <2 and as `age + I(age^2) + I(age^3)` if age ≥2

The [article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6655747/) also provide an example: a patient with PTB=36, FTB=18, age=39, perineum not involved, sex=male, and time to admission=0, should result in a overall sum of coefficients*variable = -1.0573

Comment: What is the model you would like to specify? Your link is to an abstract of a paywalled article (which is inaccessible to most), so not helpful. It would be better to edit your question and write out the model that you would like to specify, as well as to *include reproducible sample data*. Good luck!

Comment: edited the question to make it clearer, basically the model is a logistic model (added description) whose each variable factor is listed in the table attached

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to use different formulae depending on whether `age > 2`.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011479/19316600) may be what you're looking for.